# How do you use MS Deploy with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

I have VS2010, and I've opened up a web site. How can I now use MS Deploy to deploy to a zip file, which can be installed in a remote IIS site?

I've searched through all the menu options, but can't seem to find out where to get started.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely 100% definitely you should watch these two talks :

http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT14

http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT56?type=wmv

Ya ya I know whenever I see a link to a talk I think 'I don't have time for this', but they're both really informative and cover web transformations, deployment and TFS deployments.

---

**Edit:** If you *really* dont have time - then check out my similar question...

"[How can I get TFS2010 to run MSDEPLOY for me through MSBUILD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636153/how-can-i-get-tfs2010-to-run-msdeploy-for-me-through-msbuild)"

... and if this confuses you then go back and watch the talk :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer:** 
Microsoft just released their "web deployment projects" for visual studio 2010. 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=711a2eef-b107-4784-9063-c978edc498cd#AdditionalInfo

After adding a web deployment project to your website (right click on the website name, click "add web deployment project") you can then build the package and use msdeploy to deploy your application.

**Old answer:**
A "web site project" cannot be packaged with MSDeploy through the GUI (at least not in the RC). You must convert your website into a "Web Application Project". Then you will have the full publishing/msdeploy capabilities.

Here is a link on how to convert a website to a web application project: http://gurustop.net/blog/2008/08/03/converting-vs-2008-website-to-web-application/

Once you convert to a web application project in Solution Explorer right click on the project name and click "Build Deployment Package".

Comment: note: this is Beta software, but it was released 4/12 which is the same date that VS2010 RTM was released. so obviously 'web deployment projects' are not included in VS2010 out of the box - if you're looking for them like I was. you need to install 'beta' software on your shiny new VS2010 RTM :-(

Comment: @simon I've installed this beta software yesterday, it seems like it's identical to the 2008 web deployment projects. It's also working fine. I agree that this should have been bundled with the RTM. :)

Comment: Thanks Lemkepf, but it seems to be the "same old stuff", So what about all the hype I watched on channel9, about being able to adjust IIS settings, setup appPools, and install certificates, etc. any ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to do it through the GUI. All the other stuff can be done, it just takes a bit more work. You'll have to execute "msdeploy" directly to do that. Which video were you referring too so I'm understanding what you are trying to do. Thanks